# R: aggregate quarterly data to hourly data - different behaviour with same date fields

Tags: r, date, aggregate, average, mean

I am trying to understand why R behaves differently with the "aggregate" function. I wanted to average 15m-data to hourly data. For this, I passed the 15m-data together with a pre-designed "hour" array (4 times the same date per hour, taking the original POSIXct array) to the aggregate function.

After some time, I realized that the function was behaving odd (well, probably the data was odd, but why?) when giving over the date-array with

```
strftime(data.15min$posix, format="%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

However, if I handed over the data with

```
cut(data.15min$posix, "1 hour")
```

the data was averaged correctly.

Below, a minimal example is embedded, including a sample of the data.
I would be happy to understand what I did wrong.

Thanks in advance!

```
d <- 3
bla <- read.table("test_daten.dat",header=TRUE,sep=",")
data.15min <- NULL
data.15min$posix <- as.POSIXct(bla$dates,tz="UTC")
data.15min$o3 <- bla$o3

hourtimes <- unique(as.POSIXct(paste(strftime(data.15min$posix, format="%Y-%m-%d %H"),":00:00",sep=""),tz="Universal"))

agg.mean <- function (xx, yy, rm.na = T) 
# xx: parameter that determines the aggregation: list(xx), e.g. hour etc.
# yy: parameter that will be aggregated
{
    aa <- yy
    out.mean <- aggregate(aa, list(xx), FUN = mean, na.rm=rm.na)
    out.mean  <- out.mean[,2]
}

#############
data.o3.hour.mean <- round(agg.mean(strftime(data.15min$posix, format="%m/%d/%y %H"), data.15min$o3), d); data.o3.hour.mean[1:100]

win.graph(10,5)
par(mar=c(5,15,4,2), new =T)
plot(data.15min$posix,data.15min$o3,col=3,type="l",ylim=c(10,60)) # original data
par(mar=c(5,15,4,2), new =T)
plot(data.date.hour_mean,data.o3.hour.mean,col=5,type="l",ylim=c(10,60)) # Wrong 

##############
data.o3.hour.mean <- round(agg.mean(cut(data.15min$posix, "1 hour"), data.15min$o3), d); data.o3.hour.mean[1:100]

win.graph(10,5)
par(mar=c(5,15,4,2), new =T)
plot(data.15min$posix,data.15min$o3,col=3,type="l",ylim=c(10,60)) # original data
par(mar=c(5,15,4,2), new =T)
plot(data.date.hour_mean,data.o3.hour.mean,col=5,type="l",ylim=c(10,60)) # Correct
```

Data:

[Download data](ftp://ftp.empa.ch/pub/empa/outgoing/catcos/test_daten.dat)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

The reason your results look different is that `aggregate(...)` sorts the results by your grouping variable(s). In the first case,

```
strftime(data.15min$posix, format="%m/%d/%y %H")
```

is a character vector with poorly formatted dates (they do not sort properly). So the first row  corresponds to the "date" `"01/01/96 00"`.

In your second case,

```
cut(data.15min$posix, "1 hour")
```

generates actual POSIXct dates, which sort properly. So the first row corresponds to the date: `1995-11-04 13:00:00`.

If you had used

```
strftime(data.15min$posix, format="%Y-%m-%d %H")
```

in your first case you would have gotten the same result as using `cut(...)`